# Class "config" does not exist Laravel 9

Tags: config, cpanel, laravel-9

I have a Laravel 9 project which works fine on local, but after uploading it to the online server I get this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "config" does not exist in /.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:875 Stack trace: #0
```

This project is not in the root folder but inside another folder, because I have multiple laravel projects. The other one laravel 8.8 is working fine.

That's what I've tried so far:

- delete vender folder and install again
- delete files in cache folder
- run command `$ php artisan optimize:clear`
- run these commands :

```
composer install
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

- nothing wrong with my .env file, I just left the default of Laravel

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726803/fatal-error-uncaught-reflectionexception-class-config-does-not-exist)

Comment: already did everything suggested in that link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue.
I had some missing php extensions on the server. Installing them solved the issue.

Check the Laravel 9 System Requirements [here in their doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/deployment#server-requirements).

run this code on your server to see your installed extensions and install everything that is missing.

```php
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
echo "<pre/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the content of **bootstrap/cache** first:

```
cd bootstrap/cache/
rm -rf *.php
```

Then run:

```
cd ../../
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: still same problem

Comment: @Yu_Jain check in your .env file if there is extra space or not a proper indention. improper .env file is also the reason of this error.

Comment: nothing wrong with my .env file, I've even left the default of laravel and copied the one of my working project but same issue.