# Laravel PHP extensions installed but not loading on VPS Server

Tags: php, linux, laravel, apache, ssh

I am running PHP version 8.3 on AlmaLinux 9. I have a Laravel 10 project that runs perfectly well on my Windows local machine because all the requirements according to [**documentation**](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment#server-requirements) are met. But I am here trying to do the same on my VPS so that it too can run, but to no avail. The issue is when I run `php -m`, on `ssh cli`, I see clearly that, there are some missing extensions; `mbstring` and a couple of others. Installing them with `sudo dnf` as can be seen below, the response is they are already installed:

```
[user@235 ~]$ sudo dnf install php-bcmath php-curl php-fileinfo php-mbstring php-mysqlnd php-pdo_mysql php-zip
[sudo] password for user:
Last metadata expiration check: 4:25:36 ago on Fri 22 Dec 2023 01:05:30 AM UTC.
Package php-bcmath-8.3.1-1.el9.remi.x86_64 is already installed.
Package php-common-8.3.1-1.el9.remi.x86_64 is already installed.
Package php-common-8.3.1-1.el9.remi.x86_64 is already installed.
Package php-mbstring-8.3.1-1.el9.remi.x86_64 is already installed.
Package php-mysqlnd-8.3.1-1.el9.remi.x86_64 is already installed.
Package php-mysqlnd-8.3.1-1.el9.remi.x86_64 is already installed.
Package php-pecl-zip-1.22.3-1.el9.remi.8.3.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Running `php -m` on `ssh` gives:

```
[root@235 ~]# php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
date
dom
filter
ftp
hash
json
libxml
openssl
pcntl
pcre
Phar
posix
random
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

And `php -m` on a local Windows machine gives:

```
PS C:\Users\KlemLloydMwenya\webapps\my-app\backend\be-a> php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl // <--- See this here
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring // <--- See this here
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO // <--- See this here
pdo_mysql // <--- See this here
Phar
random
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

**What I have already tried:**

- Added extensions to `php.ini` file, and even restarted the server with `/sbin/service httpd restart`, `sudo systemctl restart httpd` and even manually restarting, as well as system rebooting **WHM**.
- Some of the issues I have followed and read are:

1. [Issue 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73350551/class-config-does-not-exist-laravel-9/73350602#73350602)
2. [Issue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73350551/class-config-does-not-exist-laravel-9)

The path to my php.ini is `/opt/cpanel/ea-php83/root/etc/php.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the PHP extensions in question were available but needed to have their respective install buttons in WHM, toggled on; and then provision them to fully install them and make them available.

Answer (score 1):

> The path to my php.ini is /opt/cpanel/ea-php83/root/etc/php.ini

So, you are not running AlmaLinux but a heavily altered by cpanel distro.

> dnf install php-bcmath php-curl php-fileinfo php-mbstring php...

This command is useless are you are not using this PHP.
Try

```
which php
/usr/bin/php -m
```

You probably need to install extensions for cpanel.