# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "config" does not exist in /var/...../Illuminate/Container/Containex.php:877

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Durign execute command php artisan optimize this error showing

[root@cel html1 php artisan optimize

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "config" does not exist in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:877
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(877) Relectiondises-> construct!)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(758) Illuminate\Container\Container-build() #2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(851): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(694): iluminate\Foundation\Application->resolve()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(836): Illuminate\Container\Container->make() #5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1423): Illuminate\Foundation Application->make()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(472) Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet() #7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(523): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->getDefaultDriver()
#B /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(111): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->parneDriver() #9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(583): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->driver() #10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(252): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->error()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(366 ) Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report()
#12 # /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(131): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException()
13 /var/www/html/artisan (37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
#14 (main)
Next Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target clann (config) does not exist. in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/
Stack trace:
#0
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(758) Illuminate\Container\Container->build()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php (851): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(694): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve() ): Illuminate\Container\Container->make()
3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(836 #4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1423 ): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()

/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(472): Illuminate\Container\Container-offsetGet()
#5 #6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(523): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->getDefaultDriver()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php (111) Illuminate\Log\LogManager->parseDriver()
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php (583): Illuminate\Log\LogManager->driver()
#8 #5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/111uminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php (252): 111uminate\Log\LogManager->error()
$10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(366): Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler->report() #11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(131): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException()
#12 /var/www/html/artisan (37): 111uminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()
$13 (main) thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 879
[root@letl html]

Tomorrow for a backup process all storage is occupied, so I'm deleted the backup zip file after that
Change the config and vendor folder from the backup file.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), especially regarding [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make it easier for people to assist you, thus improving your chances at getting an answer. In your particular case, what exactly IS your question?

Answer (score 0):

**delete cache in laravel :**

run `php artisan optimize:clear`

or

`cd bootstrap/cache/ && rm -rf *.php`

for more information => [Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57727359/20355717)